# jQuery.bind("remove")

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

Is there a way have an event handler run when a DOM element is removed?  I have not seen this documented anywhere.  It seems it might be possible since jQuery is able to remove data and events on element removal.

Answer (score 3):

Binding `DOMNodeRemoved` will allow for you to detect removal of nodes inside the bound element. Works in Firefox, Iron and Opera... but not IE.

**jQuery**

```
$("#detectchanges").bind("DOMNodeRemoved",function(){
  alert('Something inside of detectchanges was terminated.');
});

$("#clickme").click(function(){
  $("#deleteme").remove();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="detectchanges">
  <div id="deleteme">Delete me</div>
</div>

<div id="clickme">Delete</div>
```

Here's [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ft5h/).